# Numpy arrays containing iterable objects

Tags: python, numpy

Normally it's possible to put arbitrary objects into numpy arrays:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass
np.array([ Foo() ])
>>> array([<__main__.Foo object at 0x10d7c3610>], dtype=object)
```

However, it appears that objects implementing `__len__` and `__getitem__` are "unpacked" automatically:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __len__(self): return 3
    def __getitem__(self, i): return i*11
np.array([ Foo() ])
>>> array([[0, 11, 22]])
```

Is there any way to stop numpy from unpacking objects in this way? What I want is to put some objects into a numpy array and have them be stored as the objects themselves, without being unpacked. So the desired behavior is:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __len__(self): return 3
    def __getitem__(self, i): return i*11
np.array([ Foo() ])
>>> array([<__main__.Foo object at 0x10d7c3610>], dtype=object)
```

Now I understand that the duck typing idea implies that numpy should unpack anything that looks like a list. But perhaps it's possible to mark the class `Foo` in some way to tell numpy not to unpack it? For example, an ABC like:

```
numpy.Nonenumerable.register(Foo)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = numpy.empty(appropriate_shape, dtype=object)
x[:] = your_list_of_foos
```

For example, for a 1-dimensional array of 1 Foo,

```
x = numpy.empty([1], dtype=object)
x[:] = [Foo()]
```

This has the benefit of working for types you don't control or that other parts of the system may wish to be unpacked. For example, if you want your list of 2 lists to be treated as a 1D array of lists,

```
x = numpy.empty([2], dtype=object)
x[:] = [[], []]
```

Comment: +1, although I'd use `empty` rather than `zeros`, more for conceptual reasons than practical ones.

Comment: @DSM: Misremembered how `empty` behaves for a dtype of `object`. I thought it would be full of arbitrary memory addresses, rather than `None`. Switched the code to use `empty`.

Comment: This works, thanks! However, creating numpy arrays in this way is pretty inconvenient, particularly because it doesn't allow things like `np.dot([Foo(),Foo()], [Foo(),Foo()])`, since in that case numpy does the conversion from list to ndarray internally. Of course it's possible to rewrite this using `np.empty` as you described, but it blows up the expression quite a bit. You did answer my question as stated, though, so I'm ticking this - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The intent of numpy is to work on numbers. So it's expected that unpacking those lists would be the correct behavior in a single-dimensional array (I.E. you're producing a concatenation of vectors).

What you probably want is an [n-dimensional array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html), or perhaps a [matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html).

Alternatively I believe you may be able to get the desired result using the optional parameters of the `array` [constructor](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array)

```
np.array(MyListOfLists, dtype = list)
```

Comment: This *is* an n-dimensional array.

Comment: I do understand why this is numpy's default behavior and I agree it makes sense as default behavior. I was hoping there was a way to explicitly ask numpy not to unpack my objects, though. FWIW using the dtype parameter to the constructor does not help: `np.array([Foo()], dtype=object)` -> `array([[0, 1, 2]], dtype=object)`

Answer (score 0):

perhaps enclose your array-like object in a container?

```
class Bar():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
```

np.array([Bar()])